# How to delete all non-free or contrib packages?

Tags: debian, apt, free-software

After completely changing my `sources.list`, I'd like to only have packages which I can update, obviously. Does `apt` do this automatically? How can I find out?

How can I delete all packages at once which cannot be reached with my actual `sources.list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Identifying packages which are no longer available

The most useful tool to list packages which need to be checked in this situation, is [`apt-show-versions`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/apt-show-versions). Install that, then run it as follows:

- `apt-show-versions | grep "No available version in archive"`

  to list all packages which aren’t available *at all* with your current repository configuration (and should be removed).
- `apt-show-versions | grep "newer than version in archive"`

  to list all packages whose currently installed version is newer than the versions available with your current repository configuration (and which you might wish to downgrade).

You can obtain similar information using `apt list --installed` and looking for `[installed,local]`, but that doesn’t distinguish between packages which aren’t available from your configured repositories and packages which are available, but in an older version than the currently installed one.

`aptitude` can show you this too; start it and look for the “Obsolete and Locally Created Packages” section in the TUI. That will contain all the packages which aren’t available from your configured repositories. You can list the packages using

```
aptitude search '~o'
```

in your shell too.

#### Deleting packages which are no longer available

`aptitude` provides the simplest answer to your actual question:

```
aptitude purge '~o'
```

will purge all “obsolete” packages (*i.e.* packages which are no longer available from the repositories).

#### Identifying and deleting contrib or non-free packages

`aptitude` can also identify contrib or non-free packages without needing to remove the corresponding repositories:

```
aptitude search '~i ~scontrib/.*' '~i ~snon-free/.*'
```

You can purge them directly:

```
aptitude purge '~i ~scontrib/.*' '~i ~snon-free/.*'
```

Answer (score 1):

## How to identify all non-free or contrib packages

You can identify contrib and non-free packages with vrms

```
sudo apt install vrms
vrms
```

Comment: Although if there are tailor-made packages for my problem, I prefer using the ones I already have.